# C# new DateTime object add only month and date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to create a new DateTime object and so:

```
endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month+1, 1).AddDays(-1);
```

Although, this code occur an error when current month is December, because is the last month of the year. What is/is there a way to avoid passing the year when creating a new DateTime object?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What date do you expect?

Comment: Change logic like this: `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)`

Comment: What exactly are you after, first of next month?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get the last date of the current month. Maybe use `AddMonths(1)`,  then backtrack from there? note that if DST happens at a month end it could get fun...

Comment: `DateTime today = DateTime.Today; DateTime monthEnd = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));`

Comment: It seems doesn't accept it because is the last month of the year. Is working fine after suffixing the month in separate. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a date without a year.

To handle "month problem" just do this.

```
endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Worked fine after suffixing the month in separate. Thank you.